# How to set the additional_attribute column value in Magento2 during import

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

How to get the `additional_attributes` columns values from Product export in Magento2.

For eg: if I want attributes like color, manufacturer, i have set the color attributes as `Filterable with results` and assigned some values in admin, but when i export the `csv`, i get this column blank.

And also while import if i set `color=White` for that column, where does the value reflect in admin.